# Get name from user with specific id PHP, SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a Firstname (Voornaam), and Lastname (Achternaam) from my database with a specific ID.

And I want to put it in my a function.

I made the following function in functions.php:

```
<?php

/* Naam opvragen */
include('gegevens.php');
function getName($getID)
{
    $getname = 'SELECT * FROM KlantGegevens WHERE ID = ' .  $getID;
    $query = $conn->query($getname);
     while($show = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

         $voornaam = $show["Voornaam"];
         return $voornaam;
     }
}
/* Eind naam opvragen */

?>
```

And i call the function with ($getID (=1)):

```
<?php getName($getID); ?>
```

My error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/thijsgp51/domains/thijskempers.nl/public_html/beheer/functions/functions.php on line 8
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: It doesn't return a name

Comment: You need to call the function with the two parameters

Comment: Your function `getName() ` doesn't have access to `$conn`, which you probably define in `gegevens.php`. Also, why does your function contain the result variables as parameters? You want to get the name based on the ID, so the ID is the input, the names are the output. Not the other way around.

Comment: And just for having said it: Don't use `mysql_*()` functions. Please take a look at MySQLi or PDO, so you can use prepared statements and make your code safe against intrusion attempts.

Comment: Thanks, i made my question a little clearer, maybe it's easier now?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    /* Naam opvragen */
    function getName($getID)
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=test', 'root', 'usbw');
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM klantgegevens WHERE ID ='$getID' ");
        $stmt->execute();
         while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

             $voornaam = $row["voornaam"];
             return $voornaam;
         }
    }

    $id = 1;
    echo getName($id);

?>
```

I used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for the connection try it. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) post on sqlinjection very helpful.

In the code i changed your query a bit and put the connection in the function like Till Helge said.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try It.

```
<?php

    /* Naam opvragen */
    function getName($getID)
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=test', 'root', 'usbw');
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM klantgegevens WHERE ID ='%s",$getID);
        $stmt->execute();
         while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

             $voornaam = $row["voornaam"];
             return $voornaam;
         }
    }

    $id = 1;
    echo getName($id);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your function definition, remove those 2 arguments, and change concatenation from `+` to `.`:

```
function getName()//or with optional arguments: function getName($voornaam='', $achternaam='')
{

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
    $getID = 1;
    $getname = 'SELECT Voornaam, Achternaam FROM KlantGegevens WHERE ID = ' .  $getID;
    $query = $conn->query($getname);
     while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

         $voornaam = $row["Voornaam"];
         $achternaam = $row["Achternaam"];

         return $voornaam.' '.$achternaam;
     }
}
```

You don't need name and forename in function definition parameters because you get it from database.

As Till Helge pointed out, you still need to open connection to database - either put it as an argument, or call as the first thing inside your function (I have already put that there after edition):

`$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');`

Comment: You didn't take into account, that the database connection is not available in the function scope.

Comment: @TillHelge Yes, I didn't, shame on me... I already edited, thanks

Comment: Thanks, i made my question a little clearer, maybe it's easier now?

Comment: And I made my answer clearer by adding `$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');` - you need to open your connection to database (with your hostname, username, pasword and db name of course), or pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: I have opened my connection in gegevens.php which i include

Comment: include it inside the function, or pass it in the function's parameter: `getName($getID,$conn);`

Answer (score -1):

Your funcion get 2 arguments

```
function getName($voornaam, $achternaam)
```

you should remove the areguments as you are not using it.

```
function getName() {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i made my question a little clearer, maybe it's easier now?

Answer (score -3):

you didn't pass parameters in your function,

```
<?php getName(); ?>
```

Comment: Wow...you really want this reputation, hm? You didn't even provide a **correct** code example, but just copy and pasted the wrong line. That's pretty...disturbing.

Comment: I pasted correct line only, i'm i wrong, he didn't pass arguments in getName(), i mentioned his error that's what i did, its not about answering, its about pointing his error

Comment: Thanks, i made my question a little clearer, maybe it's easier now?

Comment: @helb This looks like an attempted answer to me.

Comment: @Duncan Ayyanar G said it himself: "its not about answering, its about pointing his error".